# My web site on AWS with Django does not apply CSS files on Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-s3

My web site that is made by Django and deployed on AWS does not apply CSS files after I uploaded CSS files to Amazon S3 using collectstatic.

```
[ec2-user]$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

I checked one of CSS files on Amazon S3, but I am not sure which one is the URL target I should set in settings.py.

[image]

Which part of settings.py I write below should I change?

Thank you.

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

#################################################################
#####     Static Files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
#################################################################
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

#################################################################
#####     Amazon S3
#################################################################
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage"    
AWS_LOCATION = "static"  
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "mydomain-bucket"
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-northeast-1"    
# AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = "%s.s3.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = "{}.s3.{}.amazonaws.com".format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_S3_REGION_NAME)
# AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load django_bootstrap5 %}

<head>
  <link href="{% static 'some-of-app/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

firefox

```
<link href="https://mydomain-bucket.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/static/some-of-app/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Python 3.9
Django 4.1
Apache 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I could solve this problem.
I blocked "public access", default of Amazon S3.
After I removed the check, my web site could apply CSS files.